# Evaluating real integral using complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to compute the following integral:
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^4}dx$$

I'll not write down everything I've done, but choosing the branch cut on the positive real axes we have that:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^4}dx=\pi i \sum_{z_i}Res(f,z_i) \qquad z_i\in\{\pm \sqrt{i},\pm\sqrt{-i}\}$$

So we have to compute four residues.
My thought was changing the branch cut by putting it on the negative imaginary axes. We can do it by choosing $arg(z) \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$. So we have that:

$$(1+i)\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^4}dx=2\pi i \sum_{z_i}Res(f,z_i) \qquad z_i\in\{e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}},e^{i\frac{3\pi}{4}}\}$$

By doing this, we now need to compute only two residues. But I'm really finding difficulties in computing those residues: in fact I can't obtain the result I'm expecting. Can you please show me the computation and tell me if my argument was clear and correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is better to first substitute $x=u^2$ and proceed.

Comment: Ok, but it's an exercise to gain confidence with branch cuts. So I'll go for the standard way.

Comment: You have to write the poles according to the branch-cut.

Comment: Haven't I done it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you are using the Hankel/keyhole contour to express the "real" integral in terms of residues? Probably some people would understand this, but others might not, so adding a few words about that aspect might make your question more useful to people...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\root{x} \over 1 + x^{4}}\,\dd x = {1 \over 4}\pi\sec\pars{\pi \over 8}} = {1 \over 2}\pi\root{1 - {\root{2} \over 2}} \approx 0.8501: {\Large ?}}$. Hereafter, I'll perform an evaluation of $\ds{\oint_{\cal C}{\root{z} \over 1 + z^{4}}\,\dd z}$ where $\ds{\cal C}$ is defined in each *particular case* for the chosen $\ds{\root{z}}$-branch cut.

---

$\ds{\Large\left.\mbox{a}\right)}$
The $\ds{\root{z}}$-branch cut is given by
$$
\root{z} = \root{\verts{z}}\expo{\ic\arg\pars{z}/2}\,,\quad
0 < \arg\pars{z} < 2\pi\,\quad z \not= 0
$$
which is the *OP choice*. Poles are given by
$\ds{p_{n} =
\expo{n\pi\ic/4}\ \mbox{with}\  n = 1,3,5,7}$.
Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\oint_{}{\root{z} \over
1 + z^{4}}\,\dd z} =
2\pi\ic\sum_{\braces{p_{n}}}{\root{p_{n}} \over 4p_{n}^{3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}
\,\pi\ic\sum_{\braces{p_{n}}}p_{n}\root{p_{n}}
=
\pi\root{1 - {\root{2} \over 2}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
Also,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\oint_{}{\root{z} \over
1 + z^{4}}\,\dd z} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\root{x} \over
1 + x^{4}}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] + & \require{cancel}
\cancel{\mbox{integration over arc with}\ \pars{\mbox{radius}\ \to \infty}}
\\[2mm] & + \int_{\infty}^{0}{\root{x}\expo{\ic\pi} \over
1 + x^{4}}\,\dd x =
2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\root{x} \over
1 + x^{4}}\,\dd x\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
With (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}):
\begin{align}
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\root{x} \over
1 + x^{4}}\,\dd x} & =
\bbx{{1 \over 2}\pi\root{1 - {\root{2} \over 2}}}
\approx 0.8501 \\ &
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\Large\left.\mbox{b}\right)}$ I guess the following evaluation is *the simplest one* because it involves just *ONE pole*: The integration is performed along a quarter circle in the complex plane first quadrant. The $\ds{\root{z}}$-branch cut is given by
$$
\root{z} = \root{\verts{z}}\expo{\ic\arg\pars{z}/2}\,,\quad
-\pi < \arg\pars{z} < \pi\,\quad z \not= 0
$$
which is the *principal one*. The contour encloses the pole
$\ds{p = \expo{\pi\ic/4}}$.
Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\root{x} \over 1 + x^{4}}\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\pi\ic\,{p^{1/2} \over 4p^{3}} -
\int_{\infty}^{0}
{\root{y}\expo{\pi\ic/4} \over 1 + y^{4}}\,
\ic\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\pi\ic\,
\expo{3\pi\ic/8} +
\ic\expo{\pi\ic/4}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\root{y} \over 1 + y^{4}}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] \implies &\ 
\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\root{x} \over 1 + x^{4}}\dd x =
{\pars{-\pi\ic/2}
\expo{3\pi\ic/8} \over 1 - \ic\expo{\pi\ic/4}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{1 \over 2}\pi\root{1 - {\root{2} \over 2}}}
\approx 0.8501 \\ &
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\Large\left.\mbox{c}\right)}$

[Ramanujan's Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem):
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\root{x} \over 1 + x^{4}}\dd x}
\,\,\,\stackrel{x^{4}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{\color{red}{3/8} - 1} \over 1 + x}\dd x
\end{align}
Note that
$\ds{{1 \over 1 + x} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-x}^{k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\color{red}{\Gamma\pars{1 + k}}{\pars{-x}^{k} \over k!}}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\root{x} \over 1 + x^{4}}\dd x} =
{1 \over 4}\bracks{\Gamma\pars{3 \over 8}
\Gamma\pars{1 - {3 \over 8}}}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over 4}\,{\pi \over \sin\pars{3\pi/8}} =
{1 \over 4}\,\pi\sec\pars{\pi \over 8}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{1 \over 2}\pi\root{1 - {\root{2} \over 2}}}
\approx 0.8501 \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain me better the second process? By the way, awesome and complete answer. Thanks, What I needed.

Comment: @DoctorK_ Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The calcus of the residues are relatevely simple when you have simple poles.

Infact, if $z_0$ is a simple pole then $f(z) = a_{-1}(z-z_{0})^{-1}+ \sum\limits_{n \geq 0}a_n(z-z_0)^n$

So $(z-z_{0})f(z) = (z-z_{0})^{-1}+ \sum\limits_{n \geq 0}a_n(z-z_0)^n$ which implies

$$\text{Res}(f,z_{0}) = a_{-1} = \lim\limits_{z \to z_0}(z-z_{0})f(z)$$

This result to be useful when we condiser $f$ of the form $\frac{f}{q}$ with $p,q$ holomorphic function, $p(z_0) \ne 0$ and $z_0$ a simple pole of $q$ since

$$\text{Res}(f,z_{0})= a_{-1} = \lim\limits_{z \to z_0}(z-z_{0})\frac{p(z)}{q(z)} = \frac{p(z_0)}{q'(z_0)}$$

**In general :**

For higher order poles a strategy could be : If $f$ has a pole of order $k$ in $z_0$, $g(z) = (z-z_0)^k f(k)$ extends to an holomorphic function in $z_0$ (I'm gonna call it improperly by $g$ as well)

With this setting $$f(z) = a_{-k}(z-z_0)^k + \cdots + a_{-1}(z-z_0)^{-1} + \sum\limits_{n \geq 0}a_n(z-z_0)^n$$

$$g(z) = a_{-k} + \cdots + a_{-1}(z-z_0)^{k-1} +  \sum\limits_{n \geq 0}a_n(z-z_0)^{n+k}$$

So $a_{-1}$ is the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{k-1}$ in the expansion of $g$ which is holomorphic. Knowing that $a_{n} = \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}$ we have $$\text{Res}(f,z_{0}) = a_{-1} = \frac{g^{(k-1)}(z_0)}{(k-1)!}$$

Hope this helps with your calculations.

Comment: Everything is clear, and I'm actually using these strategies. But I suppose I'm having problems with material calculus.

Comment: Could you please show me the computation?

Comment: In this question, however, $f(z)=\frac{\sqrt z}{1+z^4}$ is not analytical for $z\neq-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Under $x^4\to x$,
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^4}dx=\frac14\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^{5/8}(1+x)}dx. $$
Let
$$ f(z)=\frac{1}{z^{5/8}(1+z)}. $$
Let $C_r, C_R$ be circles at $0$ cut from $r$ to $R$, respectively, and $C_1, C_2$ be the top and bottom parts of the segment from $r$ to $R$. Then, for big $R>0$ and small $r>0$,
$$ \int_{C_R}f(z)dz+\int_{C_r^-}f(z)dz+\int_0^{R}f(x)dx-\int_0^{R}f(xe^{2\pi i})dx=2\pi i\text{Res}(f,z=-1). $$
Clearly
$$ \bigg|\int_{C_R}f(z)dz\bigg|\le\frac{1}{R^{5/8}(R-1)}2\pi R=\frac{2\pi R^{3/8}}{R-1}, \bigg|\int_{C_r^-}f(z)dz\bigg|\le\frac{1}{r^{5/8}(1-r)}2\pi r=\frac{2\pi r^{3/8}}{1-r} $$
and
$$ \int_0^{R}f(xe^{2\pi i})dx=e^{-5\pi i/4}\int_0^\infty f(x)dx, \text{Re}(f,z=-1)=e^{-5\pi i/8}. $$
So letting $R\to\infty, r\to 0^+$, one has
$$ (1+e^{-5\pi i/4})\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=2\pi i e^{-5\pi i/8} $$
or
$$ \int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\frac{2\pi i e^{-5\pi i/8}}{1+e^{-5\pi i/4}}=\frac{\pi}{\cos(\pi/8)}. $$
Thus
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^4}dx=\frac14\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^{5/8}(1+x)}dx=\frac{\pi}{4\cos(\pi/8)}. $$