# Contour integral in presence of a branch cut.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log x}{1+x^3}dx$$

and I have to use Residue Theorem. I chose the classical pacman contour centered in the origin, and by using little/big circle theorems I can state that:

$$(2+2\pi i)\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{1+x^3}dx=2\pi i\sum_{z_i} Res(f,z_i)$$
where $z_i$ are the poles. Computing the residues we have:

$$Res(f,-1)=\frac{i\pi}{3}$$
$$Res(f,e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}})=\frac{i\pi}{9}e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$$
$$Res(f,e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}})=-\frac{i\pi}{9}e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$$

And so
$$2\pi i\sum_{z_i}Res(f,z_i)=2\pi i(\frac{i\pi}{3}+\frac{i\pi}{9}e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3}}-\frac{i\pi}{9}e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}})=-\frac{2\pi^2}{3}+\frac{2\pi^2}{9}(2i\sin(\frac{2pi}{3}))$$

But clearly I'm making mistakes as the result doesn't match. Can you please help me spot it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use
$$ f(z)=\frac{\log}{z^3+1} $$
the integral becomes
$$ \int_0^\infty f(x)dx+\int_{\infty}^0f(xe^{2\pi i})dx=2\pi i\text{Res}(f,z_1,z_2,z_3). \tag1$$
Since
$$ \int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^3+1}dx $$
and
$$ \int_{\infty}^0f(xe^{2\pi i})dx=-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log x+2\pi i}{x^3+1}dx $$
putting them in (1), the integral you wanted will be cancelled. For this type of integrals, you have
$$ f(z)=\frac{\log^2z}{z^3+1} $$
instead of
$$ f(z)=\frac{\log z}{z^3+1}. $$

Comment: Checked, can't obtain result even with this..

Comment: When I have time, I will check.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Thanks a lot, haven't thought about it! How do you come up with this idea?
By the way, there's another question left if you want. I'm glad to give you upvotes and points, consequently.

Comment: Glad I can help you. Which question?

Comment: You mean this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3906934/evaluating-real-integral-using-complex-analysis?

Comment: I will check that one.

Comment: Yep, that one! You found it :)